Unknown HTML/JS error when implementing Stripe on Squarespace
I've been trying to implement a simple stripe form on squarespace using the code block, but I'm getting this error. Any idea how to troubleshoot? ChatGPT isn't helping.

Access to fetch at 'https://merchant-ui-api.stripe.com/elements/wallet-config' from origin 'https://js.stripe.com' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.

This is my HTML
<!-- Include the Stripe.js library -->
<script src="https://js.stripe.com/v3/"></script>

<div class="course-details-container">
  <h1>10-Week Python Course for Minorities</h1>
  <p>Join our comprehensive 10-week Python course designed specifically for minorities. Learn the fundamentals of Python programming and gain the skills needed to succeed in the tech industry.</p>
  
  <h2>Course Details</h2>
  <ul>
    <li><strong>Duration:</strong> 10 weeks</li>
    <li><strong>Start Date:</strong> July 22nd-October 12th 2024</li>
    <li><strong>Format:</strong> Live and Virtual</li>
    <li><strong>Instructor:</strong> Babatunde David Ogundipe</li>
  </ul>
  
  <h2>What You'll Learn</h2>
  <ul>
    <li>Python basics: syntax, variables, and data types</li>
    <li>Control structures: loops and conditionals</li>
    <li>Functions and modules</li>
    <li>Working with libraries and APIs</li>
    <li>Object-oriented programming</li>
    <li>Data manipulation and analysis</li>
    <li>Automation</li>
    <li>Building projects and portfolios</li>
  </ul>
  
  <h2>Enroll Now</h2>
  <p>To secure your spot in the course, please fill out the form below:</p>
  
  <form id="payment-form">
    <label for="amount">Select Amount:</label>
    <select id="amount" name="amount" required>
      <option value="200">Donation - $2</option>
      <option value="18000">Tuition - $180</option>
      <option value="50000">Full Tuition - $500</option>
    </select>
    <label for="name">Name:</label>
    <input type="text" id="name" name="name" required>
    <label for="email">Email:</label>
    <input type="email" id="email" name="email" required>
    <div>
      <label for="card-element">Credit or debit card</label>
      <div id="card-element"></div>
      <div id="card-errors" role="alert"></div>
    </div>
    <button id="submit">Submit Payment</button>
  </form>
</div>

<!-- Custom CSS for styling -->
<style>
  .course-details-container {
    font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
    max-width: 800px;
    margin: auto;
    padding: 20px;
    background-color: #f9f9f9;
    border-radius: 8px;
    box-shadow: 0 2px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  }
  .course-details-container h1 {
    color: #333;
    font-size: 24px; /* Reduced font size */
  }
  .course-details-container h2 {
    color: #333;
    font-size: 20px; /* Reduced font size */
  }
  .course-details-container p, .course-details-container ul, .course-details-container li {
    font-size: 14px; /* Reduced font size */
  }
  .course-details-container ul {
    list-style-type: disc;
    padding-left: 20px;
  }
  #payment-form {
    margin-top: 20px;
  }
  #payment-form label {
    display: block;
    margin-bottom: 8px;
    font-size: 14px; /* Reduced font size */
  }
  #payment-form input, #payment-form select, #payment-form textarea {
    width: 100%;
    padding: 10px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    border-radius: 4px;
    font-size: 14px; /* Reduced font size */
  }
  #payment-form button {
    padding: 10px 20px;
    background-color: #28a745;
    color: white;
    border: none;
    border-radius: 4px;
    cursor: pointer;
    font-size: 14px; /* Reduced font size */
  }
  #payment-form button:hover {
    background-color: #218838;
  }
  #card-element {
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    padding: 10px;
    border-radius: 4px;
    font-size: 14px; /* Reduced font size */
  }
  #card-errors {
    color: #fa755a;
    margin-top: 10px;
  }
</style>

<!-- Your custom JavaScript for Stripe Elements integration -->
<script>
  document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
    var stripe = Stripe('pk_live_51PSrG8RxlYkqL9qpR8tgNraE3e55q1oWJ37M2HQKqIQ5T48J8P9uj6WLETmQGrQs6xaKpSTOYcrsCXy6jcFdxMNh000XhnUFzj');  // Replace with your Stripe publishable key
    var elements = stripe.elements();
    
    var style = {
      base: {
        color: '#32325d',
        lineHeight: '24px',
        fontFamily: '"Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, sans-serif',
        fontSmoothing: 'antialiased',
        fontSize: '16px',
        '::placeholder': {
          color: '#aab7c4'
        }
      },
      invalid: {
        color: '#fa755a',
        iconColor: '#fa755a'
      }
    };

    var card = elements.create('card', {style: style});
    card.mount('#card-element');

    card.on('change', function(event) {
      var displayError = document.getElementById('card-errors');
      if (event.error) {
        displayError.textContent = event.error.message;
      } else {
        displayError.textContent = '';
      }
    });

    var form = document.getElementById('payment-form');
    form.addEventListener('submit', function(event) {
      event.preventDefault();

      // Get selected amount
      var amountSelect = document.getElementById('amount');
      var amount = amountSelect.options[amountSelect.selectedIndex].value;

      fetch('https://your-heroku-app.herokuapp.com/create-payment-intent', {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({
          amount: parseInt(amount)  // Amount in cents
        }),
      }).then(function(result) {
        return result.json();
      }).then(function(data) {
        if (data.error) {
          var errorElement = document.getElementById('card-errors');
          errorElement.textContent = data.error;
        } else {
          stripe.confirmCardPayment(data.clientSecret, {
            payment_method: {
              card: card,
              billing_details: {
                name: document.getElementById('name').value,
                email: document.getElementById('email').value
              }
            }
          }).then(function(result) {
            if (result.error) {
              var errorElement = document.getElementById('card-errors');
              errorElement.textContent = result.error.message;
            } else {
              // The payment succeeded
              alert('Payment pre-authorized! We will contact you soon.');
            }
          });
        }
      });
    });
  });
</script>

This is my backend python code to create the payment
from flask import Flask, request, jsonify
import stripe
from config import api_key
from flask_cors import CORS


stripe.api_key = api_key

app = Flask(__name__)
CORS(app)  # Enable CORS for all routes


@app.route('/create-payment-intent', methods=['POST'])
def create_payment_intent():
    """
    Endpoint to create a payment intent. This pre-authorizes a payment
    but does not capture the funds until later.
    """
    try:
        data = request.json  # Get the JSON data from the request body
        if not data:
            return jsonify(error="No JSON payload provided"), 400
        
        # Extract amount from the request data
        amount = data.get('amount')
        if not amount:
            return jsonify(error="Amount is required"), 400

        # Validate amount (only accept $180 or $500)
        if amount not in [200,18000, 50000]:  # Amounts in cents
            return jsonify(error="Invalid amount"), 400

        # Create a PaymentIntent with manual capture method
        intent = stripe.PaymentIntent.create(
            amount=amount,  # amount in cents
            currency='usd',
            payment_method_types=['card'],
            capture_method='manual',  # Set to manual to pre-authorize the payment
        )
        # Return the client secret to the client
        return jsonify({'clientSecret': intent['client_secret'], 'paymentIntentId': intent['id']})
    except stripe.error.StripeError as e:
        # Handle Stripe-specific errors
        body = e.json_body
        err = body.get('error', {})
        return jsonify(error=err.get('message')), 403
    except Exception as e:
        # Handle general errors
        return jsonify(error=str(e)), 500


at a guess (no code, no context, almost no information at all) you're trying to access a resource directly from the browser that should be accessed via your server

@JaromandaX please look at the code I added above

so merchant-ui-api.stripe.com is attempting a fetch from js.stripe.com ... neither of those are your domain, so, either you're using stripe.com wrong, or stripe.com is wrong

You might want to ask squarespace if they added any default CSP on your page, and include Stripe's directives accordingly.
